# Taking intersection of data in Hive

Tags: hive

I have in hive the following data:

```
userid cityid
1      15
2      15
1      7
3      15
2      8
3      9
3      7
```

And I want to keep only the userid's that have a cityid 15 and a cityid 7 (in my example, it would be userid's 1 and 3).
I tried:

```
select userid from table where cityid = 15 and userid in (select userid from table where cityid = 7);
```

But with hive it is not working.
Can somebody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try avoiding a self-join

```
SELECT  userid
FROM
 ( SELECT userid, collect_set( cityid) as cities
   FROM table 
   GROUP BY userid 
 )
WHERE array_contains( cities, 7 )
AND array_contains( cities, 15 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found how to do it:

```
select a.userid from (select userid from table where cityid = 15) a join (select userid from table where cityid = 7) b on a.userid = b.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM table_name WHERE cityid == 15 OR cityid == 7;
```

Comment: Actually this answer is wrong as I want users who have both cityid 15 and cityid 7.