# Query to find the intersection of three different classes

Tags: sql, hive

Trying to get the count of distinct people in the intersection of top two circles. (In the figure I am trying to get the count for the region labeled as d). Keys 1,2 and 3 belong to first circle and 4,5,6 belong to second circle and 7,8,9,10 belong to third circle.

Table structure is as follows:

```
customer       key
A234            1
A345            4
A12             5
A989            6
```

[image]

This is the query I have tried:

```
      select count(distinct(c.key))
      from (select c.key
        from tab1 c
        group by c.key
        having sum(case when key1 in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
               sum(case when key1 in (4,5,6,7,8) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
      ) c
```

Comment: how do b and a relate?

Comment: I started to answer, but then realized that your sample data, which is single, is out of line with your query, which involves three tables.  Also, the join conditions you used look suspicious.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: the sector d without g or the sector d and g ??

Comment: Take a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306593/taking-intersection-of-data-in-hive

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I have edited the question, I understand that my previous code seemed a bit confusing. The keys are associated with three different conditions in the same table. Thanks !!

Comment: Is this what you have tried? copy-paste from @GordonLinoff answer to your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712445/left-outer-join-of-3-tables

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply got your `HAVING` clause mixed up.

```
select count(*)
from 
(
  select key
  from tab1
  group by key
  having sum(case when key1 in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 -- in circle A
     and sum(case when key1 in (4,5,6) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 -- in circle B
     and sum(case when key1 in (7,8,9,10) then 1 else 0 end) = 0 -- not in circle C
) region_d;
```